# Stacking menu items under eachother with scss and a slider under it

Tags: html, css, sass

I got a menu, but I want submenus to be stacked under it.
I tried, but all the menu items were in the same spot.

Anyone know what to do?

My jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aLhPr/

I got a slider under the menu, so it needs to be on top of the slider.

My scss:

```
#menu {
  height:48px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: $myriad;
  color: $white;
  background-color: $lightpurple;
  border: 1px solid $lightpurple;
  ul {
    margin-left: -40px;
    display:block;
  }
  li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 15px;
    &:hover {
      background-color: $darkpurple;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  }
 a {    
    color: $white;
    text-decoration:none;
    &:hover{
    color: $lightgray; 
    }
        i {
            font-size:9px;
            &.icon{
                font-size:17px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure if this is exactly what you wanted. But I created a fiddle where you have submenu items on your first menu item(Leden) by using `position: absolute` on the submenu items.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aLhPr/1/)

Note that I also moved your `A` tags so they're inside of the `LI` tags. This is because having them surrounding the `LI` tags is invalid HTML.